# Is it possible to use intel integrated graphics card along with nvidia geforce 940mx?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, gaming, nvidia-geforce

Is it possible to use intel integrated graphics card along with nvidia geforce 940mx? I am using windows 10 64 bit, directx version 12. I am playing game Rise of Tomb Raider which is not smooth enough. I think using both cards may help in gaming performance. If possible, please let me know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to have 2 GPU's (that aren't in SLI or CrossFire) to run in parallel for a single game.

Although this isn't possible, there are a few things you can do to increase your computer's performance for gaming:

1. Get the latest Nvidia drivers for your system -> [Nvidia Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx).
2. Open the Nvidia Control Panel -> "Manage 3D settings", and ensure that your 940MX is set as the primary graphics card, as it should perform better in games.
3. Finally, if you are ok with higher power consumption, open the Control Panel -> System and Security -> Power Options, and set the power plan to "High Performance".

Hope this helps!